# Run shell command step by step

Tags: vb.net

I am vb.net user.
Please some one help me!
How to run shell command in step by step.
When runing shell command in projects,the projects run all command the same time.
Cann't run step by step.

Thanks....,Sorry for Spelling.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Interaction class' [Shell function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell(v=vs.110).aspx), the 3rd parameter in it is boolean Wait. Set it to True - and each Shell statement will wait for completion of the command before invoking the next one.

As far as I remember, Shell doesn't wait for *child subprocesses*, so if you start a process which starts another one and then exits (e.g. `bat` file without `call` or with `start`) - you might face some issues. In this case consider changing the complete tree of calls. Another option would be to use System.Management assembly to trace cals tree using WMI as described [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-WMI-with-C-4e5a9ee1).